# pmdarima: Apply .predict method via .groupby and .apply to auto_arima output stored rowwise in a pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pmdarima

I'm using `auto_arima` via `pmdarima` to fit multiple time series via a `groupby`.  This is to say, I have a `pd.DataFrame` of stacked time-indexed data, grouped by variable `variable`, and have successfully applied `transform(pm.auto_arima)` to each.  The reproducible example finds boring best ARIMA models, but the idea seems to work.  I now want to apply `.predict()` similarly, but cannot get it to play nice with `apply` / `lambda(x)` / their combinations.

The code below works until the `# Forecasting - help!` section.  I'm having trouble catching the correct object (apparently) in the `apply`.  How might I adapt one of `test1`, `test2`, or `test3` to get what I want?  Or, is there some other best-practice construct to consider?  Is it better across columns (without a `melt`)?  Or via a loop?

Ultimately, I hope that `test1`, say, is a stacked `pd.DataFrame` (or `pd.Series` at least) with 8 rows:  4 forecasted values for each of the 2 time series in this example, with an identifier column `variable` (possibly tacked on after the fact).

```
import pandas as pd 
import pmdarima as pm
import itertools

# Get data - this is OK. 
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nickdcox/learn-airline-delays/main/delays_2018.csv'
keep = ['arr_flights', 'arr_cancelled']

# Setup data - this is OK. 
df = pd.read_csv(url, index_col=0)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format = "%Y-%m")
df = df[keep]
df = df.sort_index()
df = df.loc['2018']
df = df.groupby(df.index).sum()
df.reset_index(inplace = True)
df = df.melt(id_vars = 'date', value_vars = df.columns.to_list()[1:])

# Fit auto.arima for each time series - this is OK. 
fit = df.groupby('variable')['value'].transform(pm.auto_arima).drop_duplicates() 
fit = fit.to_frame(name = 'model') 
fit['variable'] = keep
fit.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)

# Setup forecasts - this is OK. 
max_date = df.date.max()
dr = pd.to_datetime(pd.date_range(max_date, periods = 4 + 1, freq = 'MS').tolist()[1:])
yhat = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(keep, dr)), columns = ['variable', 'date']) 
yhat.set_index('date', inplace = True)

# Forecasting - help! - Can't get any of these to work.
def predict_fn(obj): 
  return(obj.loc[0].predict(4))
predict_fn(fit.loc[fit['variable'] == 'arr_flights']['model'])                             # Appears to work! 

test1 = fit.groupby('variable')['model'].apply(lambda x: x.predict(n_periods = 4))         # Try 1: 'Series' object has no attribute 'predict'.
test2 = fit.groupby('variable')['model'].apply(lambda x: x.loc[0].predict(n_periods = 4))  # Try 2: KeyError
test3 = fit.groupby('variable')['model'].apply(predict_fn)                                 # Try 3: KeyError
```

Comment: BTW, this code swaps the models for flights and cancellations. The output of a groupby is sorted, and `keep = ['arr_flights', 'arr_cancelled']` is not in the same order as the groupby.

Comment: Could be.  I typically work-check time-series stuff with a plot of data with forecasts.  Since I lack forecasts (so far), I didn't complete the process.